# In Android Password having four individual fields is not showing previous field as dot when moving to next field using requestfocus() in textwatcher

Tags: android

In android i have  a requirement of Password with four single number fields and i have used four edittext views. If we enter 4 numbers it has automaically fill the four fields. I have done this by using addTextChangedListener. But my password fileds are not replaced by dots except the problem. I think because of using requestfocus() to next field previous field is not converting dot. Please help me.

```
  passInput1.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(passInput1, passInput2));
  passInput2.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(passInput2, passInput3));
  passInput3.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(passInput3, passInput4));
```

and My CustomWatcher is shown below.

```
public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
      private EditText currentEditTextFiledId;
      private EditText nextEditTextFiledId;

         public CustomTextWatcher(EditText currentEditTextFiledId, EditText  nextEditTextFiledId) { 
        this.currentEditTextFiledId = currentEditTextFiledId;
        this.nextEditTextFiledId = nextEditTextFiledId;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         currentEditTextFiledId.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         Integer textlength1 = currentEditTextFiledId.getText().length();


         if (textlength1 >= 1) { 

             nextEditTextFiledId.requestFocus();

         }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I've done the same exact thing and have the same exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting way around this, by simply moving focus to whichever field should be masked first, before moving focus into the next field:

```
pinBox1.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(pinBox1, pinBox2, pinBox2));
pinBox2.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(pinBox2, pinBox3, pinBox1));
pinBox3.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(pinBox3, pinBox4, pinBox2));
pinBox4.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(pinBox4, pinBox4, pinBox3));
```

So I pass another parameter in, for the field to be changed and we just request focus there first:

```
public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText currentEditTextFieldId;
    private EditText nextEditTextFieldId;
    private EditText editTextFieldToChange;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText currentEditTextFieldId, EditText  nextEditTextFieldId, EditText editTextFieldToChange) { 
        this.currentEditTextFieldId = currentEditTextFieldId;
        this.nextEditTextFieldId = nextEditTextFieldId;
        this.editTextFieldToChange = editTextFieldToChange;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        currentEditTextFieldId.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Integer textlength1 = currentEditTextFieldId.getText().length();


        if (textlength1 >= 1) { 
            editTextFieldToChange.requestFocus();
            nextEditTextFieldId.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even in password mode, Android always shows the last entered symbol (because the buttons are small and it's easy to mispress them). In general, four number fields sounds like a bad idea. What will happen if the user presses the backspace key?

I would use a single password field with `android:inputType="number"`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

If you really want to reinvent the wheel, you may have 4 read-only text fields and 10 big buttons to input digits -- at least, you will control their behavior.

Comment: I posted my solution in another answer, but I did also code around the backspace issue as well by checking if the field is empty and moving the cursor to the previous field. Hacky, but workable.

Answer (score 0):

Post Runnable to the Current EditText. You need to make current EditText to wait until it convert enterted text to dot,then call requestFocus().

```
currentEditTextFiledId.post(new Runnable(){
     Integer textlength1 = currentEditTextFiledId.getText().length();
     if (textlength1 >= 1) { 
         nextEditTextFiledId.requestFocus();
     }
});
```